# Thanks for the new "close as duplicate" menu

Tags: discussion, user-interface, duplicate-questions

It's been a while since I actively used SO due to school. I just discovered the new interface for closing duplicates. This may not be the appropriate place to say this, but I wanted to put it in a public place:

## THANK YOU SO MUCH.

The new "close as duplicate" interface is so much better. Last I remember, checking the possible duplicate and casting your vote ended up taking about 5 seconds or more, and with the new interface I just did it in 2.

So I just wanted to say great job, SO team. Meta is so full of feature requests and bugs and complaints that I figured an honest "thank you" with no reservations was due.

(If this has been done before, and isn't allowed, sorry. Also, sorry that I'm late to the party on this one.)

Comment: Same from me as well!

Comment: I was thinking about posting this but wasn't sure on the protocol for thank-you meta questions (I hadn't seen the [original post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32690/close-exact-duplicate-process-is-buggy-and-annoying/52256#52256) about it). It is fantastic though, much better than the old way

Comment: @Michael There isn't really a protocol for thank-you questions. It seems for the most part, simply carry along with it.